# parser unable to match the consequent rule due to error evaluating a former rule

Tags: javascript, peg, pegjs

Example:

```
start = name / invocation;

name = [a-zA-Z]+ { return text() };

invocation = a:name "()" { return {type: 'inv', value: a } };
```

If input is `abc()` I am getting error:

```
Expected [a-zA-Z] or end of input but "(" found
```

However, if start was defined as follows no issues arise:

```
start = invocation / name;
```

For the earlier case, shouldn't the name rule not match and consequently enter the invocation rule? Else how to manage such a thing?

For working example, see [playground](https://repl.it/repls/TenseAwareMass)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a property of Parser Expression Grammar. Changing the order of expressions in a choice-operator can change the result.

From [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parsing_expression_grammar#Semantics):

> The fundamental difference between context-free grammars and parsing
>   expression grammars is that the PEG's choice operator is ordered. If
>   the first alternative succeeds, the second alternative is ignored.
>   Thus ordered choice is not commutative, unlike unordered choice as in
>   context-free grammars.

Comment: Shouldn't `name` rule gracefully fail and attempt to match the next rule (considering the first example)? Instead I get an exception. Is this the way it is supposed to work? To rephrase, in that choice-order itself why did I get an exception while processing `name` rule. I mean, I know the reason "why", however, I can't explain why it fatally stopped; the parser execution should have continued...

Comment: It successfully matches `name` but then finds `(` for which there is no rule. It then does not backtrack, but just throws the exception. You always have to put the most specific rules first.

Comment: There is more I'd like to discuss: if you can join the following room it would be awesome... https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/194824/temporary-pegjs-discussion-room